# Why doesn't the Go statement execute in parallel?

Tags: multicore, go, parallel-processing

I'm testing this Go code on my VirtualBoxed Ubuntu 11.4

```
package main

import ("fmt";"time";"big")
var c chan *big.Int

func sum( start,stop,step int64) {
    bigStop := big.NewInt(stop)
    bigStep := big.NewInt(step)
    bigSum  := big.NewInt(0)
    for i := big.NewInt(start);i.Cmp(bigStop)<0 ;i.Add(i,bigStep){
        bigSum.Add(bigSum,i)
    }
    c<-bigSum           
}

func main() {
    s := big.NewInt( 0 )
    n := time.Nanoseconds()

    step := int64(4)
    c = make( chan *big.Int , int(step))
    stop := int64(100000000)
    for j:=int64(0);j<step;j++{
        go sum(j,stop,step)     
    }
    for j:=int64(0);j<step;j++{
        s.Add(s,<-c)
    }
    n = time.Nanoseconds() - n
    fmt.Println(s,float64(n)/1000000000.)
}
```

Ubuntu has access to all my 4 cores. I checked this with simultaneous run of several executables and System Monitor.
But when I'm trying to run this code, it's using only one core and is not gaining any profit of parallel processing.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You probably need to review the [Concurrency section of the Go FAQ](http://golang.org/doc/go_faq.html#Concurrency), specifically these two questions, and work out which (if not both) apply to your case:

> ***Why doesn't my multi-goroutine program
>   use multiple CPUs?***
>
> You must set the GOMAXPROCS shell environment
>   variable or use the similarly-named [function](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#GOMAXPROCS)
>   of the runtime package to allow the run-time
>   support to utilize more than one OS thread.
>
> Programs that perform parallel computation
>   should benefit from an increase in GOMAXPROCS.
>   However, be aware that [concurrency is not parallelism](http://blog.golang.org/2013/01/concurrency-is-not-parallelism.html).
>
> ***Why does using GOMAXPROCS > 1
>   sometimes make my program slower?***
>
> It depends on the nature of your
>   program. Programs that contain several
>   goroutines that spend a lot of time
>   communicating on channels will
>   experience performance degradation
>   when using multiple OS threads. This
>   is because of the significant
>   context-switching penalty involved in
>   sending data between threads.
>
> Go's goroutine scheduler is not as
>   good as it needs to be. In future, it
>   should recognize such cases and
>   optimize its use of OS threads. For
>   now, GOMAXPROCS should be set on a
>   per-application basis.
>
> For more detail on this topic see the
>   talk entitled [Concurrency is not Parallelism](http://blog.golang.org/2013/01/concurrency-is-not-parallelism.html).

Comment: also note that the default seems to be "1"

Comment: The default with go1.6.3 on OSX 10.11 is the number of CPU cores. I believe it was changed in Go v1.5.