# Passing slice to function used for go routine

Tags: arrays, concurrency, go

I have the following function which takes as parameters two slices of two dimensional arrays of *ints* (where *coreCount* is amount of cores available)

```
func calculate(slice_1 [][array_size][array_size]int, slice_2 []  [array_size[array_size]int, coreCount int) {
//for each (coreCount*k + i, i = 0, ... , coreCount) matrix from slice_1 take matrix from slice_2 and check some criteria while not changing matrix under check
}
```

Slices are quite big in size (thousands of two dimensional arrays) so it's good idea to do the checking in parallel. So I simply create (in case of 4 cores compurer)

```
go calculate(slice_1 , slice_2, 4)
go calculate(slice_1 , slice_2, 4)
go calculate(slice_1 , slice_2, 4)
go calculate(slice_1 , slice_2, 4)
```

But it still calculates not in parallel. What's wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why go isn't going parallel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235317/why-go-isnt-going-parallel)

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for `func` in a `go` statement (just write `go funcName(arg1, arg2)`).

Also, we'll need the whole program (or at least a simplified, working version) to be able to help you. Have you set GOMAXPROCS?

Comment: I don't know what's GOMAXPROCS ,@justtinas

Comment: Quoting the documentation, `The GOMAXPROCS variable limits the number of operating system threads that can execute user-level Go code simultaneously.`

Basically, if GOMAXPROCS is 1 (the default now), your code will never run in parallel. Say, if you're only doing the calculations (and not I/O, etc.), your calculating goroutine will never be paused by the scheduler and goroutines won't even run concurrently.

The usual pattern is to set GOMAXPROCS to the number of CPU cores by `runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())`

Comment: @justinas Please don't encourage the use of that snippet.  See the mailing list post here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/i9xx4ke4vtc/KvApBGVJzw8J .  Instead, create a -cpus flag that becomes the value passed to `runtime.GOMAXPROCS` (which can, if you wish, default to `runtime.NumCPU()`) or document in your program help that GOMAXPROCS should be set beforehand.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware that's a wrongdoing. It's a pity I can't edit the comment anymore.

Comment: @Kyle Lemons Can you please explain your point of view and show how to correctly set GOMAXPROCS in more detail? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ArtyMathJava See the duplicate question I linked above (which explains GOMAXPROCS) and the mailing list post to which I linked (which explains why you shouldn't force GOMAXPROCS to be NumCPU).

Comment: @Kyle Lemons, Please help. I've added GOMAXPROCS as env variable and initialized it with 4. Still my program does't run in parallel. And os.Getenv("GOMAXPROCS") is blank.

Comment: Make sure you have GOMAXPROCS exported or run your code like this: `bash $ GOMAXPROCS=4 ./yourbinary`

Comment: @Volker I've run $ echo $GOMAXPROCS . And I got 4.

Comment: @ArtyMathJava Bash variables are not the same as environment variables.  Either `export GOMAXPROCS=4` or `GOMAXPROCS=4 ./yourbinary` is required for your binary to see the value.

Comment: @ArtyMathJava That's probably not a good idea, as there are lots of other Go applications which won't benefit (and may be adversely affected) by that setting.  You should really set it on a one-off basis.  Consider also the option I mentioned above, of creating a `-cpus` flag.

Comment: @ArtyMathJava That's a question for the mailing list, probably.  It's completely unrelated to this question here :).  Note that you shouldn't be setting GOROOT, GOBIN, GOARCH, GOOS, CGO_ENABLED, etc yourself.  All you need is the `go` binary in your path.

Answer (score 1):

To do some checking in parallel, your goroutines would need to look at different parts of the input data and from your very brief code sketch, at best you'd run the same calculation four times. That is, of course, assuming that you actually spawn four goroutines with the same arguments and nothing to distinguish them from each other.