# Go server performance is the same when adding more cores

Tags: multithreading, go

I am trying to understand how the go server scales when adding more cores but it seems that I can't see an improvement and I don't know why.

There does not seem to be a change in any way when increasing cores. Do I need to do something in the code to let it know that I want to use more than 1 core? Would that help on performance?

The code I am using for the test is a simple server that outputs "Hello World".

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        w.Write([]byte("Hello World"))
    })
    http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil)
}
```

I am doing the tests on virtualbox.

These results are with 1 core:

```
$ nproc
1
```

Testing with ab with 1 core:

```
$ ab -n 10000 -c 1000 http://127.0.0.1/
```

Result from ab with 1 core:

```
Concurrency Level:      1000
Time taken for tests:   1.467 seconds
Complete requests:      10000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      1280000 bytes
HTML transferred:       110000 bytes
Requests per second:    6815.42 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       146.726 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.147 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          851.93 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

Testing with wrk with 1 core:

```
$ wrk -t1 -c1000 -d5s http://127.0.0.1:80/
```

Result from wrk with 1 core:

```
Running 5s test @ http://127.0.0.1:80/
  1 threads and 1000 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency    32.32ms   15.79ms 279.10ms   77.01%
    Req/Sec    24.61k     1.89k   27.77k    64.58%
  121709 requests in 5.01s, 14.86MB read
Requests/sec:  24313.72
Transfer/sec:      2.97MB
```

Changing to 2 cores:

```
$ nproc
2
```

Testing with ab with 2 cores:

```
$ ab -n 10000 -c 1000 http://127.0.0.1/
```

Result from ab with 2 cores:

```
Concurrency Level:      1000
Time taken for tests:   1.247 seconds
Complete requests:      10000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      1280000 bytes
HTML transferred:       110000 bytes
Requests per second:    8021.12 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       124.671 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.125 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          1002.64 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

Testing with wrk with 2 cores:

```
$ wrk -t1 -c1000 -d5s http://127.0.0.1:80/
```

Result with wrk with 2 cores:

```
Running 5s test @ http://127.0.0.1:80/
  1 threads and 1000 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency    37.04ms    5.67ms  64.92ms   79.73%
    Req/Sec    26.98k     1.97k   29.71k    66.00%
  134040 requests in 5.06s, 16.36MB read
Requests/sec:  26481.38
Transfer/sec:      3.23MB
```

Testing with wrk with 2 cores and 2 threads:

```
$ wrk -t2 -c1000 -d5s http://127.0.0.1:80/
```

Results with wrk with 2 cores and 2 threads:

```
Running 5s test @ http://127.0.0.1:80/
  2 threads and 1000 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency    29.32ms   29.21ms 505.22ms   98.47%
    Req/Sec    13.48k     2.11k   18.16k    63.00%
  134121 requests in 5.03s, 16.37MB read
Requests/sec:  26680.46
Transfer/sec:      3.26MB
```

Changing to 4 cores:

```
$ nproc
4
```

Testing with ab with 4 cores:

```
$ ab -n 10000 -c 1000 http://127.0.0.1/
```

Result with ab with 4 cores:

```
Concurrency Level:      1000
Time taken for tests:   1.301 seconds
Complete requests:      10000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      1280000 bytes
HTML transferred:       110000 bytes
Requests per second:    7683.90 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       130.142 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.130 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          960.49 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

Testing with wrk with 4 cores:

```
$ wrk -t1 -c1000 -d5s http://127.0.0.1:80/
```

Result with wrk with 4 cores:

```
Running 5s test @ http://127.0.0.1:80/
  1 threads and 1000 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency    36.84ms    5.78ms  58.23ms   77.43%
    Req/Sec    26.69k     2.06k   30.19k    64.00%
  132604 requests in 5.06s, 16.19MB read
Requests/sec:  26207.42
Transfer/sec:      3.20MB
```

Testing with wrk with 4 cores and 4 threads:

```
$ wrk -t4 -c1000 -d5s http://127.0.0.1:80/
```

Results with wrk with 4 cores and 4 threads:

```
Running 5s test @ http://127.0.0.1:80/
  4 threads and 1000 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency    35.58ms   26.65ms 508.77ms   98.44%
    Req/Sec     5.82k     2.21k   10.44k    64.85%
  117089 requests in 5.10s, 14.29MB read
Requests/sec:  22972.33
Transfer/sec:      2.80MB
```

I don't know if I can use go if it "does not scale" at all, with multiple cores. I don't understand how go works compared to other languages. When I run tests with facebooks HHVM it scales no problem out of the box when adding more cores.

What can I do to see a performance gain in the go server when adding more cores?

EDIT:

After changing the initial code to:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "runtime"
)

func main() {

    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(4)

    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        w.Write([]byte("Hello World"))
    })
    http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil)
}
```

The results from wrk were different, changing the GOMAXPROCS from 1 to 4 resulted in significant increase.

Testing 1 thread 4 cores:

```
$ wrk -t1 -c1000 -d5s http://127.0.0.1:80/
```

Result for 1 thread and 4 cores:

```
Running 5s test @ http://127.0.0.1:80/
  1 threads and 1000 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency    11.00ms    4.33ms  53.58ms   83.83%
    Req/Sec    48.65k     3.30k   55.18k    81.25%
  242131 requests in 5.08s, 29.56MB read
Requests/sec:  47658.92
Transfer/sec:      5.82MB
```

Testing 4 thread 4 cores:

```
$ wrk -t4 -c1000 -d5s http://127.0.0.1:80/
```

Result for 4 thread and 4 cores:

```
Running 5s test @ http://127.0.0.1:80/
  4 threads and 1000 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency    15.47ms    8.49ms  99.35ms   80.88%
    Req/Sec    14.98k     2.98k   27.42k    78.65%
  298885 requests in 5.10s, 36.48MB read
Requests/sec:  58639.84
Transfer/sec:      7.16MB
```

But the tests with ab were the same. Does anyone know why it does not affect ab? When benchmarking with HHVM ab results also gets affected. But on go I get same results.

```
$ ab -n 10000 -c 1000 http://127.0.0.1/
```

Results:

```
Concurrency Level:      1000
Time taken for tests:   1.410 seconds
Complete requests:      10000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      1280000 bytes
HTML transferred:       110000 bytes
Requests per second:    7094.18 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       140.961 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.141 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          886.77 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't the go statement execute in parallel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235317/why-doesnt-the-go-statement-execute-in-parallel)

Comment: You're making the CPU do almost nothing. Why would you expect it to be the limiting factor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to tell the Go runtime to use more cores by setting the environment variable `GOMAXPROCS` to your desired core count. Alternatively, there is also a [function](https://godoc.org/runtime#GOMAXPROCS) to change it.

By default, this is set to one. As of [Go 1.5](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.5) it will be the number of cores in your system.

Comment: Can I just include "runtime", and do runtime.GOMAXPROCS(2) inside of main before anything else or should I do it in a special way?

Comment: @Alex correct, you just add it to the top of main (or even init()

Comment: @Alex Yes, you can do it like that. However, for testing using an environment variable might be easier. For example, you could test like this: `GOMAXPROCS=X ./YourBinary`.

Comment: I changed the code and the results from wrk increased, but not the results from ab. Does anyone know why this is the case? When doing benchmarking on facebooks HHVM on ab I do get to see the increase. But not on go for some reason.

Comment: @Alex: Because `ab` uses http1.0, and sets keepalive off by default.  A single `ab` process can't keep up with the go server, so you're basically benchmarking the benchmark tool. I recommend not using `ab` at all.

Comment: @JimB could you recommend and alternative benchmarking tool?

Comment: @dm03514: `wrk` isn't too bad, but as soon as the benchmark tool affects the measurements, you start to have problems. This server code does so little, that the benchmark tool makes a large impact on the result. Plus, not only do you have to take into account the tool's overhead, but the network, OS, and maybe even hardware (network card and drivers, numa scheduling, cache interference when running on the same host, etc). Real benchmarks are hard, and there is no one tool that does it all.